# AuthenticationHandler: sling always redirecting to gemotrix login page

Tags: aem, sling

I am implementing login functionality for my site using Custom AuthenticationHandler. When I give credentials and submit the form the AuthenticationHandler is always redirecting to geometrix site and asking geometrix credentials.

Even I tried deactivating geometrix in my author instance, after login into my site again it is redirecting to felix console site.

How to restrict other than my application pages ?

Any help is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 7):

You can change your default login page from felix console

```
http://localhost:4503/system/console/configMgr
```

Configure `Day CQ Login Selector Authentication Handler`, set the default login page to the path of your custom login page

Answer (score 0):

I guess the Day CQ Root Mapping servlet redirects you to it's configured rootmapping target.

Have at look at 
/libs/cq/core/config.publish/com.day.cq.commons.servlets.RootMappingServlet
inside crxde.
The rootmapping servlet's config targets to /content.html which is resolved to /content. redirect that to your content or if it has to coexist, then create an additional JcrResourceResolverFactoryImpl config.

Just create a `config.publish/org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.JcrResourceResolverFactoryImpl` 
node below your application in apps 
`/apps/<yourappp>/config.publish/org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.JcrResourceResolverFactoryImpl` with jcr:primaryType sling:OsgiConfig and add a resource.resolver.mapping to your like the following samples demonstrates.
    resource.resolver.mapping="[/-/,/content/intranet/-/intranet-/, ....]" />